# Push notification on production mode not receiving PNS

Tags: push, apple-push-notifications, production-environment, apns-php

I am new to PNS. I have developed one app which is having PNS and deliver ipa  to client and PNS coming properly no issues at all in development mode.Now i want to uplaod to App store before that i am creating all new certificate and profiles in production mode and tested from server but in Production mode PNS is not coming?? I have removed sandbox from PHP server side script even replaced .pem certificate name also. but still not working. Any idea what is going wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a distribution version of your app, e.g. built against a distribution provisioning profile, one of Ad Hoc/Enterprise/AppStore. Make sure the profile has a production push notification entitlement.

You can check this with

```
codesign -d --entitlements - pathTo.app
```

look for

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
```